# Change the behaviour of RET (with electric indent) to only indent the new line, not the previous one

Tags: indentation, electric-indent

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077770/how-do-i-disable-electric-indent-on-ret-but-still-keep-other-electric-characters asks and answers how to disable electric indent when pressing RET. All similar questions also seem to stop at "disable electric-indent-mode".

Out-of-the-box, RET indents the previous line and the new line. For the new line this means that it simply adds enough whitespace to make the cursor appear at the correct position.

I like the second part of the behaviour but not the first, i.e. I never want it to indent the previous line. Is there a way to change it so it gives me enough whitespace on the new line but keeping the previous line untouched?

I actually don't need/want most of the electricity. A solution which involves turning off electric-indent-mode but somehow activating the "add whitespace for new lines" feature would be fine with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll get what you want with

```
(setq-default electric-indent-inhibit t)
```

This was meant as a variable for major-modes (rather than for users), but it should take care of your use-case as well.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I stumbled upon this variable while sifting through `electric.el` but put it aside due to its documentation: "If non-nil, reindentation is not appropriate for this buffer." My interpretation of that was that it would simply disable electric-mode for this buffer...

Comment: The key is that it talks about **re**indentation, i.e. changing the indentation of an existing line, as opposed to indentation of a new line.

Comment: I like electric indent mode when I type a curly brace (for the current line). Any way to keep this behavior while preventing the previous line from changing when I press enter?

Answer (score 1):

> I actually don't need/want most of the electricity. A solution which involves turning off electric-indent-mode but somehow activating the "add whitespace for new lines" feature would be fine with me.

This approach might be of interest:

In programming modes I invariably want <kbd>RET</kbd> to invoke `indent-new-comment-line` or its mode-specific analogue, which always has a default binding of <kbd>M-j</kbd>. These functions take care of indentation, and also comment continuation when you're inside one.

```el
(defun my-coding-config ()
  ;; ...
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "M-j")))
  (local-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") 'newline)
  )

(mapc
 (lambda (language-mode-hook)
   (add-hook language-mode-hook 'my-coding-config))
 '(prog-mode-hook
   ;; plus anything not derived from prog-mode:
   inferior-emacs-lisp-mode-hook
   css-mode-hook
   python-mode-hook))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-mode-hook)
(defun my-js-mode-hook ()
  ;; Fix M-j behaviour in block comments in js-mode
  (setq-local comment-multi-line t)
  (local-set-key [remap indent-new-comment-line] 'c-indent-new-comment-line))
```